# Existence of Higgs boson in my room

Tags: higgs

someone please explain me that the room in which I am now are there Higgs boson or they can be produced only accelerators?

Answer (score 2):

There are two concepts, a) the [Higgs field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#Higgs_field) and b) the Higgs boson which is a particle in the [elementary particles table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) of the standard model.

The basic mathematical model of particle physics is based on  [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory). QFT is based on a quantum mechanical formulation which  allows for  many particle calculations. The mathematical tool used are the Feynman diagrams which are a representation of the integrals needed for calculating crossections etc.  A basic assumption of quantum field theory is that a field exists for each elementary  particle in the table, which permeates all space time, on which creation and annihilation operators generate the corresponding particle. These fields have a [vacuum expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value), (no particle  present)  of zero,  ( except for the Higgs field ).

Thus the Higgs field exists all through spacetime, your room too . To get a Higgs Boson though, a creation operator has to act on the Higgs field. Energy must be supplied larger than or equal to its mass, so in experiments this can happen only in accelerators. It can happen with cosmic rays of high energy interacting in the atmosphere, but hard to detect. It has a very fast decay time (~1.5x10^-22seconds) so there are no Higgs bosons around the way there are [cosmic source muons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/muonatm.html) ( about 1 muon per square centimeter per minute).

Comment: Why is the same true for all particles? The rest of them get created "simply" because of energy conservation and decay probabilities, no actual fields throughout space. The Higgs field though does run throughout space.

Comment: @Helen  In quantum field theory all the particles in the standard model table of particles have a field covering all space time. A photon field, and electron field etc. That is how quantum field theory works the mathematics of computing interaction crossections etc. The Feynman diagrams are a tool for the integration of what is happening when two particles interact: to have the particles, creation and annihilation operators operate on the corresponding fields. It is a succesful mathematicla model , but it is in this model that the higgs field exists.

Comment: the vacuum expectation value for all these fields is zero, except for the Higgs *field* ( I think it is about 240GeV) which is how massive particles acquire their mass.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on that point, Anna? In a vacuum, i can understand why the expectation value for any field is zero, but why is it different and nonzero for the Higgs field?

Comment: @LegitimateWorkUser It is the long  story of the standard model . Try http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/unify.html#c2  and the http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/higgs.html. It has to do with symmetries and symmetry breaking, and it is the Higgs field which breaks the symmetry an acquires a nonzero expectation value

Comment: I think that your second comment here could be the answer to your first comment. Exactly, the other fields are only mathematical tools. Afaik it's not believed in the mainstream that they have physical existence - in contrast to the Higgs field.

Comment: @Helen  I have continual confrontations with theoretical physicists here who really believe in the reality of the quantum fields. The Higgs field is as mathematical or as real as all the other fields from the particle table.

Comment: I think that the subtle point is that regardless of the fields' physical reality or not, Higgs *is* different in what regards its presence in space (which is reflected in the fact that it give mass while the other fields don't).